# MVC Routing below sub folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I need some help with the routing. I tried to find existing Questions-Answers but nothing that is helping me. In case there is a answer already, please link it.

My structure:

```
/Controller
--/Root
----/HomeController.cs
/Views
--/Root
----/Home
------/Index.cshtml
```

The problem is, that the Index.cshtml cannot be found.

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found. The following locations
>   were searched:
>
> ~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
>  
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
>  
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx 
>  
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
>  
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml 
>  
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.vbhtml
>  
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml 
>  
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml

Stacktrace:

> System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult.FindView(ControllerContext context) +382
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +116
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.b__17() +23
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245<br />
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20() +75
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +16
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +16
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>      System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +16
>      System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>      System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9721605
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

The routing is this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Home",
    url: "Root/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    ).DataTokens.Add("app", "Home");
```

Is there something I missed?

Comment: do you really need to keep your controllers and views under the `root` directory?

Comment: Yes, i want to seperate it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, MVC looks for views in `~/Views/YourControllerName` folder. Looks like you have a directory called `root` for your controllers and views. I am not sure why you want to do that. If you are doing this to organize code logically in your project, you should consider [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx).

You may create a new area called root. This will create a directory called root under `~/Areas`.  You can create controllers and views under that. When you define your routes , you do not need the to include the word `Root` in your url as you will have an Area registration starts with the word Root (which you can customize)

But if you really want to not use areas, but want to keep your views under `~/Views/root` directory, You can create a custom view engine and specify where to look for the view files.

```
public class MyCustomViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    public MyCustomViewEngine()
    {
        string[] viewLocationFormatArr=new string[4];
        viewLocationFormatArr[0] = "~/Views/root/{1}/{0}.cshtml";
        viewLocationFormatArr[1] = "~/Views/Root/{1}/{0}.vbhtml";
        viewLocationFormatArr[2] = "~/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.vbhtml";
        viewLocationFormatArr[3] = "~/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.vbhtml";
        this.ViewLocationFormats = viewLocationFormatArr;

        string[] masterLocationFormatArr = new string[4];
        masterLocationFormatArr[0] = "~/Views/root/{1}/{0}.cshtml";
        masterLocationFormatArr[1] = "~/Views/root/{1}/{0}.vbhtml";
        masterLocationFormatArr[2] = "~/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.vbhtml";
        masterLocationFormatArr[3] = "~/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.vbhtml";
        this.MasterLocationFormats = masterLocationFormatArr;

        string[] partialViewLocationFormatArr = new string[4];
        partialViewLocationFormatArr[0] = "~/Views/root/{1}/{0}.cshtml";
        partialViewLocationFormatArr[1] = "~/Views/root/{1}/{0}.vbhtml";
        partialViewLocationFormatArr[2] = "~/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.vbhtml";
        partialViewLocationFormatArr[3] = "~/Views/Shared/{1}/{0}.vbhtml";
        this.ViewLocationFormats = partialViewLocationFormatArr;

    }
}
```

Make sure to register this custom view engine in the Application_Start event.

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
var ourViewEngine = new MyCustomViewEngine();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(ourViewEngine);
```

Detailed blog about rendering views from custom location is [here](http://techiesweb.net/2012/10/16/rendering-views-from-custom-folders-in-asp-net-mvc.html).

Comment: Finally, i created my own RazorViewEngine and this is working.